# String Object to date object. Same output as String

Tags: java

I have a String `27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM`. I want it to convert it into `Date object` and Date object should be like `27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM`(Similar as my String).

I tried `SimpleDateFormat` but it gives like `Wed May 27 00:00:00 CDT 2015`.
If I used format method of `SimpleDateFormat` then it converts to `String`.

Code:
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

```
    String dateInString = "27-05-2015 10:23:31 PM";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);

        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        // String s = formatter.format(date);

        // System.out.println(s.substring(7, 9) + ":" + s.substring(27));
        // System.out.println(s.substring(0, 2) +"/");
        // Date dt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        // System.out.println(formatter.format(dt));
        // System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want Date object in exactly this format 27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @CoderNeji I think I missed one line :SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can not (String Object to date object **in same output as String**). Date class has it's own toString() method implementation.When you are printing the date object like System.out.println(date); it means it basically prints the toString() method implementation format.

toString() method of Date class

```
public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');            // EEE
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
    TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
    if (zi != null) {
        sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
    } else {
        sb.append("GMT");
    }
    sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Arin I am agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to convert your date to a Date Object

```
public class DateFormat
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
  {
    String dateString = "27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM";

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

    Date date =simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);

    System.out.println(date);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added Further checks

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
  {
    String dateString = "27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM";

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    Date date =simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
    //System.out.println(date);

    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date).equals(dateString));
  }
```

Comment: it will give out put like Wed May 27 00:00:00 CDT 2015. I want same as 27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM

Comment: If I run this I get `27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM`

Comment: System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date).equals(dateString)); gives false

Comment: Try adding the local on `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a","Locale.US");` like `Locale.US` .. what TimeZone is your default ?

Comment: Force the TimeZone by adding `simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`

Comment: No Success i got output : Wed May 27 05:23:31 CDT 2015

Comment: Are you using `HH` or `hh` as your format ? , `hh` is correct for the AM , PM

Answer (score 0):

Why to format when it is not required , You just need to parse the String using `SimpleDateFormat#parse` method

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
try{
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(yourDateInString);
}catch(ParseException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

**Update :**

Now to format parsed Date just format it using the same formatter

```
logger.debug(sdf.format(parsedDate));
```

**Output**

```
27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM
```

Comment: Beacuse i want 27-05-2015 09:01:53 PM output as a date object

Answer (score 0):

`HH` from 0 to 23 and `hh` from 1 to 12 (AM/PM). Change your format `HH` to `hh`.

**Update**

```
HH is 24 hours format.
hh is 12 hours format.
```